# jq tiny error: random select option after populating from one of two arrays

Tags: jquery, select, random

not that the problem is advanced, but the fact, that the code probably features a minor error

http://jsbin.com/apudev/9/edit

what it does is randomly picks a car from one of two lists chosen by the user.

the only thing is that the choice does not get reflected in the select field.

```
    var select = document.getElementById('s1');
    var items = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
    var index= Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    select.selectedIndex = index;
```

which elsewhere would work do not fit in the rest.

what could be wrong?

Comment: What browser are you using - this works for me in Chrome.

Comment: In firefox also it is working pretty fine.

Comment: very strange. i am using latest chrome. otherwise it works flawlessly. i am on xp 32 pro. have tried in firefox, it workd but jq layout is replaced by bare html. it does randomize the brand shown, though. on explorer 8 it is always chevrolet and ford that are chosen. what could be the cause..?

Comment: besides, why does the alert show up more that once each time? 
it looks like this: I click on the country, one alert shows up with digit 0, I click ok and another appears immediately with say digit 2. regardless of that, the car is always either chevrolet or ford, ie the first ones from the lists.